# gem executables will not run

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, rubygems

Running gem install from shell script giving error even though I ruby version2.3.0 installed on my machine.

I am trying to install a gem from sh file. sh file code is as below:

```
    cat > /tmp/install_bandshell.sh <<EOF
    #!/bin/sh -e
    cd /tmp
    git clone git://github.com/concerto/bandshell.git
    cd bandshell
    gem build bandshell.gemspec
    gem install *.gem
    cd /
    rm -rf /tmp/bandshell
    EOF
    chmod +x /tmp/install_bandshell.sh
    /tmp/install_bandshell.sh
```

But when I run this sh file get error WARNING: You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run. ERROR: Error installing bandshell-1.7.2.gem: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.

Even I install 2.3.0  gem env output

```
    RubyGems Environment:
      - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
      - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
      - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/
      - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
      - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
      - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bin
      - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
      - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/etc
      - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
        - ruby
        - x86_64-linux
      - GEM PATHS:
         - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/
         - /root/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
         - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
      - GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - REMOTE SOURCES:
         - https://rubygems.org/
      - SHELL PATH:
         - /usr/local/sbin
         - /usr/local/bin
         - /usr/sbin
         - /usr/bin
         - /sbin
         - /bin
         - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems
```

From terminal, if I install this gem it works but from shell script giving above error. Please help me with this. Platform is Debian Wheezy.

Comment: If the only difference is shell vs script, is your script correct? Is your ruby/gem environment working with /bin/sh or perhaps /bin/bash, /bin/zsh

Comment: Can you post any script/code/profile that affects your PATH?

Comment: I think @S.Spencer is right. You probably need to change `#!/bin/sh -e` to the actual shell that you use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your *primary* question only, regarding the message.  (Frankly, I don't know what's going on with your sh file, so I'm not going to address whatever other problems it causes.)

The message is a warning to you that any executables that the gem installs are not in your path.  If the gem does not install *any* executables, then you can safely ignore the message.  If it *does* (or you are simply unsure), then modify the path accordingly.  How you do that depends on what shell you happen to be using.  Since you have tagged the question with 'linux', I will guess that you are using bash; if so, add to either your `~/.profile` or to `~/.bash_profile` an entry similar to:

```
PATH="$PATH:/root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin"
```

Now, at this point, I have to wonder - *are* you using ruby-1.9?  You know that ruby 1.9 is obsolete, right?  Actually, considering that you seem to be using Ruby 2.3.0, that's not likely.  What I would suggest is to (at least temporarily) adjust your PATH as above to avoid the warning.  I suspect you *will* still have problems, but then you can ask a new question without the WARNING that you have cited.

One last point, ignore suggestions that you should change your shebang to be other than "#!/bin/sh"; that's *very* unlikely to help.

Comment: i installed ruby 2.3.0 shown as output of command gem env. Yes os is linux, Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the `WARNING: You don't have /root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run.` problem...

Try add this line on your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
export PATH="/root/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/bin:$PATH"
```